# R - Extract out multiple specific rows into another variable

Tags: r, statistics, survey, inference

[Press here for Dataset relating to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC1u5.png)

How do you extract only the Male rows into another dataset whilst keeping the rownames & column names intact?

Comment: I gave you a downvote because there is no reproducible example data or code. In addition, it is not clear what is your desired output. If you can correct those, I will consider to retract the downvote or even give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
mydf[mydf["sex"] == "Male"],]
```

has the effect you want (where mydf is the name of your dataframe). Note that `mydf["sex"]` is the column of values labeled "sex" and `mydf["sex"] == "Male"` is a column of Boolean values (TRUE where the value is "Male").

The comma with nothing between it and the right square bracket `mydf[...,]` is important. It means, select all columns.